# How to use custom loss function (PU Learning)

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am currently exploring [PU learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PU_learning). This is learning from positive and unlabeled data only. One of the publications [[Zhang, 2009]](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~dell/publications/dellzhang_ukci2005.pdf) asserts that it is possible to learn by modifying the loss function of an algorithm of a binary classifier with probabilistic output (for example Logistic Regression). Paper states that one should optimize Balanced Accuracy.

Vowpal Wabbit currently supports five loss functions [[listed here]](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Loss-functions). I would like to add a custom loss function where I optimize for AUC (ROC), or equivalently, following the paper: 1 - Balanced_Accuracy.

I am unsure where to start. Looking at the code reveals that I need to provide 1st, 2nd derivatives and some other info. I could also run the standard algorithm with Logistic loss but trying to adjust l1 and l2 according to my objective (not sure if this is good). I would be glad to get any pointers or advices on how to proceed.

UPDATE
More search revealed that it is impossible/difficult to optimize for AUC in online learning: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24660520/1093448)

Comment: John Langford confirmed that AUC can generally be optimized by changing the ratio of false positive and false negative loss. In VW, this means setting a different importance weight for positive and negative examples. You need to tune the optimal weight using a hold out set (or cross validation).

Comment: @MartinPopel Thank you! I found that for my application SVM perf from T. Joachims does the job perfecly. I can use his linear SVM implementation where the custom loss function optimizes the criterion I am looking for. There is no need for a held out set (at least for setting the weights).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two software suites that are immediately ready to do PU learning:

(1) [SVM perf](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_perf.html) from Joachims

Use the ``-l 10'' option here!

(2) [Sofia-ml](https://code.google.com/p/sofia-ml/)

Use ``--loop_type roc'' option here!

In general you set `+1'' labels to your positive examples and`-1'' to all unlabeled ones. Then you launch the training procedure followed by prediction.

Both softwares give you some performance metrics. I would suggest to use standardized and well established binary from KDD`04 cup: ``perf''. Get it [here](http://osmot.cs.cornell.edu/kddcup/software.html).

Hope it helps for those wondering how this works in practice. Perhaps I prevented the case [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: Did you find any implementation in R or Python?